# Is there a Latin construction for a tentative question/suggestion analogous to "I wonder [question word]"?

Tags: idiom

At first, I thought "me rogo," but the dictionary did not confirm my suggestion. I think my German is interfering ("ich frage mich").

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion “I wonder” is such a versatile expression in English that it is futile to wish for a direct Latin equivalent that would cover all uses.

For example, with sentence questions, “I wonder” often means little more than “maybe.”

> I haven't seen the cat in a while. I wonder if he is sleeping.
> Felem aliquamdiu non vidi. Nescio an dormiat.

On the other hand, it can also mean “I'd like to know.”

> The cat is nowhere to be found. I wonder where he is.
> Feles nusquam reperiri potest. Cupio, ubi sit, scire.

In short, avoid translating single words or expressions, and try to capture the overall tone and meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Based on German "Ich frage mich", I started out with *inquiro*, but that does not cover it. Then I wondered: would *[miror](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmiror)* do?

Comment: Traupman's excellent dictionary translates "I wonder what's up" as *miror quid hoc sit negoti*.